# How can I switch to a keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and I can't use my old keyboard layout configuration.

I used the Caps Lock key to change the layout to Hungarian.
and
I used the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to change the layout to English.

How can I set this keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu 14.04? All I can do is a previous source and next source option in All settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Typing. But I don't know which was selected in most case, so I prefer start hit caps-lock before writing Hungarian, and Shift-CapsLock when I start programming. But now I can just rotate this sources (layouts) which is non-sense to me. I am not a finite state machine to remember my keyboard layout state.

Comment: Be aware, too that there is a long standing mega-bug and Caps-Lock behavior is involved. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322 (it is not completely fixed, yet).

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do that, is by using the Gnome Tweak Tool.  To install, Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Once installed, search foe tweak in dash, and click on it to open.  Once opened, click on Typing, and then choose the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> behavior.

[image]

Comment: Doesnt work for me. But there is an option in Switching to another layout, that is selected for me (Caps Lock to first layout, Shift Caps Lock to second) but nothing happens after selecting that